# jquery tooltip is rendering behind modal window

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have applied the [JQuery Tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) to all my title elements of my site. The problem I am having is from a modal popup page the tool tip is rendered behind the modal dialog.  I think I need to change the z-order of either the tooltips or the dialogs.  But this surprises me since i'm using two features of JqueryUI together.

Here is all I am calling on document.ready()

```
$(document).tooltip();
```

and here is a screenshot to illustrate what is happening.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly, both create a new element inside the body tag. So this should be a simple z-index problem. Just find the classes (inspect elements, see what classes they have, find them... you know... usual stuff) and change z-index so the tooltip has a bigger one.

As an alternative, you could set z-index from script, when you are calling the tooltip (or the modal window, doesn't matter), but I recommend against it. A css solution is cleaner and faster.

Comment: I had left in a rule in my own css that was changing the default z-index for the dialog.